# In the game Trove, how do you get recipes for the Haunted Workbench?

Tags: trove

I have decided that the lower portions of my Cornerstone tower should be decorated with doodads from the Cursed Vale.  I have built a [Haunted Workbench](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Haunted_Workbench), but only a few recipes are unlocked.

I have read that Recipe Dungeons are a source of recipes, but I can not find any Recipe Dungeons in the Cursed Vale biome even after an hour of riding around and hopping to new instances.  I was able to find Recipe Dungeons in the Fae Forest and learn a few of the decorations for that workbench, so I know what they look like on the minimap.

How do I unlock recipes for the Haunted Workbench?

Comment: There are definitely recipe lairs in the Cursed Vale.  Perhaps there's some new bug preventing them from appearing?  If nobody else responds I can check when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally spotted a recipe lair in the Cursed Vale.  The trick is that I went through a portal to the Fae Forest and was in an "Uber"-difficulty world.  This world also included some Cursed Vale biomes nearby and I spotted the dungeon.

This leads me to believe that the difficulty of the world is the important factor.  If you use the atlas to travel directly to the Cursed Vale you end up in an Elite-difficulty world which seems to lack recipe lairs.  In between Elite and Uber is the Master difficulty which is what you get if you use the Atlas to travel to a Desert Frontier world.  The Master difficulty also seems to lack recipe lairs.

So for now when I want to hunt recipes I will travel through the Uber-difficulty portal to the Fae Forest and then search for a Cursed Vale biome of uber difficulty.